# How to handle types for injected properties in Vue Composition API - Typescript

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

```js
import firebase from 'firebase'
import Vue from 'vue'

/* This file simply imports the needed types from firebase and forwards them */
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $fireStore: firebase.firestore.Firestore
    $fireDb: firebase.database.Database
    $fireFunc: firebase.functions.Functions
    $fireStorage: firebase.storage.Storage
    $fireAuth: firebase.auth.Auth
    $fireMess: firebase.messaging.Messaging
  }
}
```

In normal typescript project with Vue 2, we can do this. But when use Composition API, how I can inject the properties like this in `root` on function `setup(_, { root})`?
So I cant use with `root.$fireStore`...

Now, I must use it with the `any` type like `(root as any).$fireStore`. So hope anyone can help my team. We are working on a project with Nuxt Composition now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, after a few days, I reached out the temporary solution for this. Just add a `nuxt.d.ts` or your `types` folder like this. So you can use `$apolloHelpers` in your Vue Instances and Middleware...

```
import { SetupContext } from '@vue/composition-api'

/**
 * @description Define type for $apolloHelpers --> copy from Apollo module --> inject Apollo Helpers
 * @docs https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module/blob/master/lib/templates/plugin.js#L141
 */

declare module '@nuxt/types' {
  interface Context {
    $apolloHelpers: {
      onLogin(token, apolloClient, cookieAttributes, skipResetStore = false)
      onLogout(apolloClient, skipResetStore = false)
      getToken(tokenName?: string)
    }
  }

  interface NuxtAppOptions {
    $apolloHelpers: {
      onLogin(token, apolloClient, cookieAttributes, skipResetStore = false)
      onLogout(apolloClient, skipResetStore = false)
      getToken(tokenName?: string)
    }
  }
}

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $apolloHelpers: {
      onLogin(token, apolloClient, cookieAttributes, skipResetStore = false)
      onLogout(apolloClient, skipResetStore = false)
      getToken(tokenName?: string)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's kind of the same in vue 3 but not the same module

```
declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
    interface ComponentCustomProperties {
        $fireStore: firebase.firestore.Firestore
        $fireDb: firebase.database.Database
        $fireFunc: firebase.functions.Functions
        $fireStorage: firebase.storage.Storage
        $fireAuth: firebase.auth.Auth
        $fireMess: firebase.messaging.Messaging
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain that? I tried, but it's doesn't work :(

Comment: ok I missread your question, I thought you wanted this.$fireStore and not root.$fireStore

Comment: Acctually, I want to do this --> root.$fireStore. I use Nuxt and have a folder `types to define the shim.d.ts` So I write code like you in vue.shimd.ts --> it's doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a composable for firebase?

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default function useFirebase() {
    return {
        fireStore: firebase.firestore.Firestore
        fireDb: firebase.database.Database
        fireFunc: firebase.functions.Functions
        fireStorage: firebase.storage.Storage
        fireAuth: firebase.auth.Auth
        fireMess: firebase.messaging.Messaging
    };
};
```

And then use it in your `setup()` of the component:

```
export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        const {fireStore, fireDb, fireFunc, fireStorage, fireAuth, fireMess} = useFirebase();
    }
});
```

Comment: Oop, it's an example. In my case, we use @nuxtjs/apollo lib --> Inject some function for apollo like `apolloHelpers` --> [Link code this function on lib](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module/blob/master/lib/templates/plugin.js#L141). Then we want to inject in `{ root }: Context` on `setup` function

Comment: Still, I think you could also achieve almost the same if you use a composable to wrap these helpers. Me personally I don't like to augment the root instance with tons of stuff. Vue router also has now two composables useRoute and useRouter instead of the injected this.$router. Seems they are working on it: https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module/issues/288

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help you, but there is root.$store.$fireAuth

Answer (score 0):

insert `@nuxt/types` in your tsconfig.json and the types will work